# SIM 2 not detected in Micromax A064

Tags: sim-card, micromax

I am using a Micromax A064.  The second SIM card is not being detected at all. The SIM in slot 2 is working fine.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Android is the device running?  Do both SIM cards work individually when in the SIM 1 slot?

Comment: @MatthewRead we are using 4.4.2 . yes both sim cards work in sim 1 slot. but in sim 2 slot it will not work. sim cards are fine. please help me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your second sim slot works at all ?. 
Have you tried putting just one sim card in the sim slot 2 ?

If it doesn't works then there can be two possible reasons for this :

Your android OS isn't detecting your sim slot 2. In simpler words, the android doesn't know there is a second sim slot. Mostly happens when you're on a custom ROM.

A hardware failure.There is some hardware issue in the second sim slot that you have on your phone!. Mostly common with Micromax devices. No offence!

One of my friends had this issue, for him the second reason was the problem!. Good Luck ! Tell me what you find. Also, do tell me which android version  you're using and what ROM you're on.

Comment: we are using 4.4.3 version.... i tried putting one sim card in the sim slot 2 , i am getting error : `please check sim card is properly inserted`. i have no idea we are using custom ROM or not. this is new mobile.

Comment: @spylh9999ggr This seems like it's  option 2 due to the above comment, hardware failure, as you don't know what ROM you are on, we can guess that you probably have never flashed anything before, therefor on stock ROM for that particular phone.